# firebase relationship Primary Key and Foreign Key

Tags: firebase, nosql, relational-database

I want to understand how to use firebase relationship Primary Key and Foreign Key
Or an example you guys can show me how to use the code I wrote in vscode.

[image]

thanks for helping

I tried searching myself and couldn't figure it out.
I hope to be able to fix the fever or to be able to do it myself after some advice.

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Firebase only has **NoSQL** database support, and neither of those supports the concept of a foreign key. If you want to stick to your relational data model and known concepts, consider looking for a relation database that meets your need. If you want to use Firebase, I recommend reading up in [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) first and then watch [Realtime Database for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) or [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: ask about relationship
SQL has primary and foreign key relationships, but Firebase doesn't have a way to manage them, how? Yes or not, brother

Comment: To be clear, Firebase "doesn't have a way to manage them" because *they do not exist* in the same way as SQL. If you can provide some sample code of what was attempted, and explain the query you're after, we may be able to help. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)